How to execute a transaction on a Gnosis Safe using Governor.sol? (getting GS020 error)
I'm trying to use a Governor.sol DAO to execute a passed proposal to transfer tokens from a Gnosis Safe. The Safe is a 1-of-2 with one of the signers being the DAO.
The last argument to safe.executeTransaction() is packed signatures. Its my understanding that I can provide null bytes here because the DAO is making the call to the Safe as one of its owners, and smart contracts can't generate their own signatures since they can't store private keys.
However, the call always fails with a GS020 (Signatures data too short) error.
Does anyone know why?
Here is a simulation:

List item

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/tallyxyz/project/simulator/64421c78-ae8e-496e-874b-f4d1115b528b?trace=0.1.3.4.1

Hey Matthew, is everything working as expected?

Thanks for your question, and apologies for the delayed response — we don't usually check Stack Exchange over the weekend.

Include a prevalidated signature
You're correct: you don’t need to provide a valid signature from the sender when executing the transaction. Instead, you should include a prevalidated signature that encodes the sender's address within the r value of the signature.
Here’s how you can generate a prevalidated signature (as referenced in the Safe{Core} ProtocolKit):
const signature =
    '0x000000000000000000000000' +
    ownerAddress.slice(2) +
    '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' +
    '01';

For instance, if the sender’s address is 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, the prevalidated signature would look like this:
'0x000000000000000000000000aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' + // r
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' + // s 
'01' // v

Or as a single string:
0x000000000000000000000000aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

When you include this prevalidated signature with the executor’s address (in your case, the DAO's address) encoded, the smart contract will recognize it as the sender’s signature. It then verifies the encoded address against msg.sender.
When the smart contract detects that v (the last byte of the signature) is set to 01, it will either approve the signature if the executor's address is correctly encoded within it, or it will validate the signature by locating a corresponding approved hash.

I hope this clears things up! If it does, please mark your question as answered on Stack Exchange. Feel free to ask any follow-up questions in the comments.
